# Matlab FFT doesnt show right frequency with measured signal, Script tested with sinus signal workes

Tags: matlab, fft

Hei Guys I am having some trouble getting the right frequency in my FFT Matlab script.
I tested the script with a sinus signal and it workes just fine. but somehow with my measured signal (put in a txt file, see below) doesn't give me the right frequency.
In the first plot I am plotting my signal and there I measured and calculated from hand the *should be frequency, which is 33.333 kHz*

```
% Parameter
td = 100*4e-6;  % Duration of the measurement ( i honestly just put something here)
fs = 250e3;     % samplingfrequency

% Frequency to be detected (measured from data in plot)
freq_soll_20 = 1/(7.2e-5 - (4.4e-5 + 4e-5)/2);
% Samples calc

s_20 = readmatrix('fft_cut_20.txt');
t_20 = 0:1/fs:((length(s_20)-1)*1/fs);

%% ---- Triggerdata
figure(1)
subplot(3,1,1);
plot (t_20, s_20)
grid on;
xlabel('Zeit (ms)');
ylabel('ADC LSB');
title('20um');

h_20=fft(s_20).*1/length(s_20);
f_20=1/td*(0:(length(t_20)-1));

subplot(3,1,2);
stem(f_20,abs(h_20));
grid on;
xlim([min(f_20) max(f_20)]);
xlabel('Frequenz (Hz)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Ausgabe des FFTs');

subplot(3,1,3);
f2_20=f_20-round(max(f_20)/2);
stem(f2_20, fftshift(abs(h_20)));
grid on; 
xlabel('Frequenz (Hz)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title(['Ausgabe des FFTs nach sortieren mit FFTSHIFT mit soll frequenz:'...
    num2str(freq_soll_20) 'Hz']);
```

the data is:

```
11284, 11601, 12033, 12355, 12344, 11985, 11558, 11444, 11807, 12491, 13090, 13199, 12694, 11878, 11290, 11500, 12855
```

my FFT gives me the frequency 1250*10^4 Hz.
I tested this code with a sinus with these parameter and it worked just fine:

```
%Parameter
fs = 250000;  % Abtastrate
td = 100*4e-6;    % Dauer der Messung
f1 = 30000;    % Frequenz

% Samples berechnen
t  = 0:(1/fs):td;
s  = sin(2.*pi.*f1.*t);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A correct formula for the frequencies would be:

```
f_20=(0:(length(t_20)-1))*fs/length(t_20);
```

Your formula `f_20=1/td*(0:(length(t_20)-1));` would be equivalent whenever `td` corresponds to the total signal duration, which is the case for your sine wave. The same cannot be said of your other signal which just has 17 samples, whereas `td=100*4e-6` with a sampling rate of 250kHz corresponds to 100 samples.

Comment: i was looking at the problem with a colleague and we came to this solution:  f_20= 1/(length(s_20)/fs)*(0:(length(t_20)-1)); and it workes. I also tried your code which gives me the same result. Thank you for answering :)